# A generic error occurred in GDI+. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gdi+

```
enter code here    

 Blog.ImageIndex = "images.jpg";
                    if (Blog != null)
                    {
                        Blog.ImageIndex = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(imageblog.FileName);
                        imageblog.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Images/ProductImages/" + Blog.ImageIndex));
                        ImageResizer img = new ImageResizer();
                        img.Resize(Server.MapPath("/Images/ProductImages/" + Blog.ImageIndex),
                            Server.MapPath("/Images/ProductImages/Thumb/" + Blog.ImageIndex));
                    }
```

I am having a GDI+ generic error I've tried what everyone says which is make sure that the folder containing the image file that is being read in like so